# How to calculate the number of days in the current month/year

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any methods available for `NSDate/NSCalendar` to calculate the number of days in the current month and current year ?

The only thing I saw is to get the number of days from a given date or between two dates.
Is this the only way ?

Comment: But I need the current month/year, not a given month and I actually don't see how the number of days in a year is calculated.

Comment: I do wish people can justify the down votes, so I can learn from my mistakes, but from my point of view this is a great question to which I couldn't find an answer yet on stackoverflow.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate because I assumed that the linked-to answer works before both months and years. Then I realized that that is not the case, therefore I have reopened the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a method which works for both months and years:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = NSDate()

// Calculate start and end of the current year (or month with `.Month`):
var startOfInterval : NSDate?
var lengthOfInterval = NSTimeInterval()
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Year, startDate: &startOfInterval, interval: &lengthOfInterval, forDate: date)
let endOfInterval = startOfInterval!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(lengthOfInterval)

// Compute difference in days:
let days = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: startOfInterval!, toDate: endOfInterval, options: [])
print(days)
```

(You may want to add some error checking instead of forcibly unwrapping
optionals.)

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date()

// Calculate start and end of the current year (or month with `.month`):
let interval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: date)!

// Compute difference in days:
let days = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: interval.start, to: interval.end).day!
print(days)
```

Comment: Yep, this works for both month and year (just by changing the .Year field inside rangeOfUnit). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let days = cal.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit: .Month, forDate: date)

print("\(days) in the month of \(date)")
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. That works great. How can I calculate the number of days in a year ? I tried same code but with .Year instead of .Month for inUnit field, but it doesn't seem to work.